# How to turn DNA list sequences into Protein sequences in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bioinformatics, dna-sequence

Here are my current values I am working with:

```
DNA_list=['ATTGAT','CTGGCA','TAGGAC','GAGGCT'] #transcription
RNA_list=['UAACUA','GACCGU','AUCCUG','CUCCGA']
protein_list=['_L','DV','IL','LR']
```

I need help turning a list of DNA sequences into Protein sequences. Essentially the program should read the RNA_list in 3 pairs to mimic a codon reading, and then take the 3 sequence and pull the values from a dictionary or anything that has the amino acids stored on there (so like BioPython or some other module). Here is what I have so far, but I have only been able to accomplish this from a single sequence not a list:

```
  codon = {"AAA":"K", "AAC":"N", "AAG":"K", "AAU":"N", 
           "ACA":"T", "ACC":"T", "ACG":"T", "ACU":"T", 
           "AGA":"R", "AGC":"S", "AGG":"R", "AGU":"S", 
           "AUA":"I", "AUC":"I", "AUG":"M", "AUU":"I", 
           
           "CAA":"Q", "CAC":"H", "CAG":"Q", "CAU":"H", 
           "CCA":"P", "CCC":"P", "CCG":"P", "CCU":"P", 
           "CGA":"R", "CGC":"R", "CGG":"R", "CGU":"R", 
           "CUA":"L", "CUC":"L", "CUG":"L", "CUU":"L", 

           "GAA":"E", "GAC":"D", "GAG":"E", "GAU":"D", 
           "GCA":"A", "GCC":"A", "GCG":"A", "GCU":"A", 
           "GGA":"G", "GGC":"G", "GGG":"G", "GGU":"G", 
           "GUA":"V", "GUC":"V", "GUG":"V", "GUU":"V", 

           "UAA":"_", "UAC":"Y", "UAG":"_", "UAU":"T", 
           "UCA":"S", "UCC":"S", "UCG":"S", "UCU":"S", 
           "UGA":"_", "UGC":"C", "UGG":"W", "UGU":"C", 
           "UUA":"L", "UUC":"F", "UUG":"L", "UUU":"F"}
protein_seq = ""
for x in range(0, len(RNA_list),3):
       codon=RNA_list[i:i+3]
       protein_seq += RNA_codon[codon]
```

Again the problem is this only works for single sequences, not lists. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: *Essentially the program should read the RNA_list in 3 pairs to mimic a codon reading, and then take the 3 sequence and pull the values from a dictionary or anything that has the amino acids stored on there* can you please elaborate

Comment: Hello! For each RNA sequence in the RNA_list, the program should break down into 3 pairs for a codon reading. This way it can be translated to its corresponding amino acid (through the codon). That should then be what appears on the final list with the proteins. The last part is simply if anyone has an easier way to translate the codons rather than having to put the entire dictionary of values like seen above. I hope this helped clarify, if not please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't this work ?

```
result = []
for rna in RNA_list:
    protein_seq = ""
    for i in range(0, len(rna),3):
           codon=rna[i:i+3]
           protein_seq += RNA_codon[codon]
    result.append(protein_seq)
```

Comment: you use `for x in range()` as your iterator but then use `i` as your index... typo?

Comment: indeed, i copied his code without noticing this

Answer (score 0):

```py
result = []
for rna in RNA_list:
    protein_seq = ""
    for i in range(0, len(rna), 3):
        rna_codon = codon[rna[i:i+3]]
        protein_seq += rna_codon
    result.append(protein_seq)
print(result)
```

`i` and `x` are different variables. You need two loops, the outer one to loop over the list of sequences, the inner one over each sequence.

Note that the result is different to `protein_list`, the second element is `DR`, not `DV`.